# alias_maps in postfix like GMail does

Tags: email, vps, postfix-mta, webmin

I would love to configure my postfix/virtualmin setup so that when I create an email account test@test.com, it would also catch all the mails sent to test+spam@test.com. Gmail offers this functionality, though, I wouldn't have a clue how to do this.

What I've done already is Googled it, http://www.virtualmin.com/node/27709 is what I've stumbled upon. Though, unable to understand 'the answer', I thought maybe someone here could help me out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Postfix and virtualmin both support alias "like" gmail with simple config.
Just go to "System Information > Postfix Mail Server > General Options" (`http(s)://<yourserver>:<vitualminport>/postfix/general.cgi`). Search for "Separator usernames / address extensions" field (press ctl+f and type "address extensions", for quick search) and fill it with "+".

Alternatively you can edit `/etc/main.cf` and place a line like

```
recipient_delimiter = +
```